# Can I some hop prevent database drop when using GrpahChat?

Tags: memgraphdb

I've added my personal OpenAI key to Memgraph Lab. I'm testing the integration now.

Can I some how prevent user from writing drop all data in OpenAI LLM integration in Memgraph Lab? Is there something like write/delete protect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know GraphChat currently does not have such features. You can prevent user from dropping all the data only with Memgraph Enterprise now, which offers [role based access control](https://memgraph.com/docs/configuration/security#role-based-access-control-enterprise).